# JRubyClassLoader not getting released

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jruby, classloader, finalizer

We're running a small JRuby on Rails app under Tomcat 6.0.28 with a Spring-based backend. I've spent some time with the Eclipse Memory Analysis tool and I can definitely tell that instances of the `JRubyClassLoader` are leaking. I setup our webapp to only use a single JRuby runtime and then I effectively did a hot-deploy to Tomcat by `touching` the war. After doing that a few times, I can see several instances of the `JRubyClassLoader` sitting around.

Since the classloader isn't getting released, the classes it loaded aren't getting released and we're running out of PermGen space.

Using Eclipse Memory Analysis, I can see the path to the GC root looks like:

```
org.jruby.util.JRubyClassLoader
  jrubyClassLoader org.jruby.Ruby
    runtime org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream
      reference java.lang.ref.Finalizer
        next java.lang.ref.Finalizer
```

And the list of `next java.lang.ref.Finalizer` goes on seemingly forever... to point where I can't seem to find the actual GC root.

If run the *Leak Suspects* report, the #1 suspect is "java.lang.ref.Finalizer", loaded by "<system class loader>".

Any ideas why the Finalizer is sticking around?

**EDIT**

As a possibly related side note, every time I do a hot deploy, a get a slew of `NullPointerExceptions`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kenai.jffi.Function.finalize(Function.java:177)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)
```

**EDIT 2**

I upgraded to JRuby 1.5.1 and I'm still seeing the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting. another evidence that `finalize()` should not be used.

it's not your fault and there's not much you can do about it.

maybe try to convince JRuby team to drop `finalize()`? shouldn't JRuby take care of resource deallocation at the earliest time instead of waiting till GC? Developers *using* JRuby are not interfacing with these objects, they are all under the control of JRuby.